# Pyrebase order_by_child not ordering data

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, desktop-application, pyrebase

I'm developing a desktop app using python and Firebase as the backend.

Since there might be lots of data, I need to get the data paginated and sorted by the parameter "Timestamp". So I'm using this:

```
raw_data = db.child("UploadedImages").order_by_child("Timestamp").start_at(self.start_from).limit_to_first(3).get()
```

("self.start_from" is a double, representing the timestamp of the last objects received)

But the returned data is not sorted and starts from the first index.
The weird thing is that it works just fine on another firebase project with the exact same structure but fewer data.

I've also skipped pagination and tried this code and the result was the same:

```
raw_data = db.child("UploadedImages").order_by_child("Timestamp").get()
```

after getting the data, I store it in another variable as a dict like this:

```
parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(raw_data.val()))
```

And then iterate the "parsed" variable and parse the data to my image class:

```
for i in parsed:
    image = models.Image(parsed[i])
```

Here's an example of my data in Firebase:
[my Firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEYN7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in a JSON object are by definition unordered, so when you call `raw_data.val()` any information on ordering is lost.

For that reason the `order_by_child` calls is useful to filter the data on the server, but it is not useful (in this context) to actually get the data in a specific order. You will need to re-order the data in your application code after it's been retrieved.

Comment: I see. So order_by_child is useless then? Isn't there an alternate to raw_data.val() to make sure the ordering isn't lost?

Comment: In the REST API ordering is only useful to then filter on those values. Since the REST API exposes JSON (which you see as a dictionary in python), the ordering is lost.